# Matlab: Looping a function on the elements of a 3-array vs Passing a 3-array to the same function

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix, operator-overloading

In Matlab I have an array *v* of length *m*, a matrix of order *n* and a function *F* that takes as an input a *single* matrix and outputs a number. Starting from *v* I would like to apply the function to the whole array of matrices whose i-th element consists of a matrix M_i whose entries are obtained by multiplicating all the entries of *M* by *v_i*. The output would be itself an array of length n.

As far as I can see there are two ways of achieving this:

1. Looping on all i=1:n, computing *F* on all the *M_i*s and store all the corresponding values in an array
2. Defining a 3-array structure that contains all the matrices M_i and correspondingly extending the function *F* as to act on 3-arrays instead of matrices. However this entails overloading some matrix operators and functions (transpose,  exponential, logarithm, square root, inverse etc...) as to formally handle a 3-array.

I have done the simpler option 1. It takes a long time to execute. Number 2 promises to be faster- However, I am not sure if this is the case, and I am not familiar with overloading operators on Matlab. In particular: how to extend a matrix operator to a 3-array in such a way that it performs the related function on all of its entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop is probably no slower than vectorising this, especially for larger problems where memory starts to limit speed. Nevertheless, here are two ways of doing it:

```
M=rand(3,3,5) % I'm using a 3x3x5 matrix
v=1:5
F=@sum % This is the function

M2=bsxfun(@times,M,permute(v.',[2 3 1])) % Multiply the M(:,:,i) matrix by v(i)
R=arrayfun(@(t) F(M2(:,:,t)),(1:size(M,3)).','UniformOutput',false) % applies the function F to the resulting matrices
cell2mat(R) % Convert from cell array to matrix, since my F function returns row vectors

R2=zeros(size(M,3),size(M,1)); % Initialise R2
for t=1:size(M,3)
    R2(t,:)=F(M(:,:,t)*v(t)); % Apply F to M(:,:,i)*v(i)
end
R2
```

You should do some testing to see which will be more efficient for your actual problem. The vectorised version should be faster for small problems, but use more memory, whereas the `for` loop will be slower for small problems but use less memory, and so could be faster on larger problems.

Comment: The vectorised solution is indeed slightly slower than looping, which already took too long. I think the size of my problem makes it unapproachable with a high-level language like matlab. Thanks anyway